# Props value is Undefined while passing through Context API in REACT

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, 2d-context-api

My Provider File of Context API (Exp file)

```
import react form 'react';
import {createContext} from "react";

export const ContextforFile = createContext();

export function ContextData(props){
   let rdata=props.data
return(
   <>
  <p>{rdata}</p>  //I am able to Get the Data here NO ISSUES TILL HERE
  <ContextforFile.Provider value={rdata} >{props.children}</ContextforFile.Provider>
  </>
);
}

function A() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContextData data="Sara" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default A;
```

My App.js File

```
import Exp, { ContextData } from './afterlogin/patirel/patmain';
import Experiment from './experi';
import {Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as React from 'react';

function App() {
 

  return (

   <ContextData>

    <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route index element={<Exp/>} />
      <Route path="/experi" element={<Experiment/>} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
    </ContextData>

  );
}

export default App;
```

only props.data value is not coming here while other values can be easily obtained
This is Experi file Where I want to get my values my Consumer File

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { ContextforFile } from './afterlogin/patirel/patmain';

export default  function Experi(){

const first= useContext(ContextforFile);
return(
    <div>
   <h1>ISSUE is Here Other VALUES are COMING BUT NOT props.data: {first}</h1>
    </div>
);

  }
```

Please help! It's been days and i cannot figure out what am i missing? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your function `ContextData` does not return anything. Yoo should return the `ContextforFile.Provider`

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write return here, in my file return is mentioned it still doesn't work please check it one more time

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of getting the undefined value could be many things.

for Example:

maybe, you are getting undefined from **props.data**. maybe because
you are not providing the default value to **createContext**.

try the following steps these may help you.

1. You must pass the default value to **createContext** if needed.

```
export const ContextforFile = createContext([value it could be any thing like array, string or object etc.]);
```

2. when you create a hook you have to write the code something like this.

Your version:
`const first= useContext(ContextforFile);`

recommended version:
`const useFirst= () => useContext(ContextforFile);`

3. Use this hook something like this.

```
const first= useFirst()
```

> here you can find the difference: [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-api-defaultvalue-forked-m3et39)

Comment: I tried, It is not working thanks for your help

Comment: did you check your props?? because I can see you are not passing any prop to ContextData.

Comment: try to pass some random text not the direct value of 'rdata' in the value prop. like value={'hello world'}.

Comment: I am able to pass the string values but not prop values any value inside "" are being passed and also i am able to manage the state also but the problem is "props" keyword even though i am storing it in a variable "const rdata" just because the data is from prop i.e props.data it is making it undefined on the consumer page. I have passed props in ContextData in the Exp file 
--> export function ContextData(props) if that is what you mean

Comment: you are not passing any prop to ContextData in App.js. just pass a prop then check it.

Comment: tried it, still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245733/discussion-between-abhi-shek-and-mirza-umair).